# Develop control algorithms in Ros

Tags: control, ros, matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi users:

Can I develop a control algorithms in Ros? I mean that it is easier to develop in Matlab, but why? what are the differences?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211327/develop-control-algorithms-in-ros/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-06-17**:
In general, I find it easier to prototype algorithms in Matlab. Once you know that the algorithm is "ready", you can switch to C++ to make it faster and port it to ROS.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can I develop a control algorithms in Ros?

Sure, you can definitely develop control algorithms in ROS.

> it is easier to develop in Matlab, but why? what are the differences?

Ease of development depends a lot on what you want to do, how much existing work you can leverage (and don't have to implement yourself) and the workflow you're most comfortable with. So, it cannot be generally said that ROS is easier than Matlab, or the other way around. In fact, Matlab and ROS are not exclusive, as the former has [ROS bindings](http://es.mathworks.com/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html), which allows you (up to a certain extent) to combine the two in a way that suits you best.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with Adolfo: it ultimately depends on your definition of ease. For me however (as an engineering, not IT-student) I would say Matlab is easier because my knowledge of C++/Python is limited and I have always worked with m-code. I'm happy I stayed away from Matlab for my current project though where I'm sacrificing development speed for run time speed. I think it's worth the effort as I probably won't always have Matlab at my disposal.

---

Originally posted by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) with karma: 47 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience, it depends on how much you want to achieve. The key point is at simulation step. If you only try with simple dynamic model of the system (few equations), Matlab is prefered. If you want to try advanced simulation (Gazebo, V-Rep) with many complicationted robots and sensors, ROS is prefered. I do not say we can not do the same thing with Matlab but it will take more time and efforts. Remember that, ROS is produced after Matlab. It means that the inventors in the early day had seen some problems with Matlab.

---

Originally posted by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) with karma: 60 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1